# minify html in golang to delete extra spaces and next line characters

Tags: go

How to create html minifier?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func HtmlMinify(html string) string {
    // todo: minify html
    return html
}

func main() {

    htmlExample := `<li>
                        <a>Hello</a>
                    </li>`
    minifiedHtml := HtmlMinify(htmlExample)
    fmt.Println(minifiedHtml) //  `<li><a>Hello</a></li>` is wanted
}
```

outputs:

```
<li>
                        <a>Hello</a>
                    </li>
```

But I want it to be

```
<li><a>Hello</a></li>
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bFVE7e-nJq)

Comment: For future reference, [Minify HTTP middleware](https://github.com/jeevatkm/middleware) using [tdewolff/minify](https://github.com/tdewolff/minify)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your example could involve simply removing spaces, but minifying html is a bit more complex than that (for instance, you don't want to remove spaces where they actually matters, like within a string).

You can see an example in:

- [**dchest/htmlmin**](https://github.com/dchest/htmlmin) ([doc](http://godoc.org/github.com/dchest/htmlmin))
- [**tdewolff/minify**](https://github.com/tdewolff/minify) (more complete) ([doc](http://godoc.org/github.com/tdewolff/minify))

Answer (score 9):

I used [tdewolff/minify](https://github.com/tdewolff/minify):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/tdewolff/minify"
)

func HtmlMinify(html string) string {
    m := minify.NewMinifierDefault()
    b := &bytes.Buffer{}
    if err := m.HTML(b, bytes.NewBufferString(html)); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return b.String()
}

func main() {

    htmlExample := `<li>
                        <a>Hello</a>
                    </li>`
    minifiedHtml := HtmlMinify(htmlExample)
    fmt.Println(minifiedHtml) //  <li><a>Hello</a>
}
```

Comment: This code currently not work. Library may be updated.